# Add more parameters to jQuery output

Tags: jquery

I already have some output from a jQuery function, say:

users => "1", "2", "3", "4"

Now, I have some data that looks like '4', '3' ,'4', '4', it is an array.

I need to add a piece of data as count => "4", "3", "4", "4" to my existing output and post the overall output

```
users => "1", "2", "3", "4"
count => "4", "3", "4", "4"
```

to my controller. How do I append this new parameter?

Comment: How are you looking to append it? Do you mean combine the arrays? Combine into a string? Sort for unique? Not present? Please try to explain a bit more as to what you are looking to accomplish with this.

Comment: I have modified my post a little, say its not a string, its just an array, how do it pass it as a parameter, in a POST ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var users = [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ];
var count = [ "4", "3", "4", "4" ];
var data = {
  users: users,
  count: count
};

$.post('/whatever_route', data, function(res) {});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. one more thing, how to access 'users' from data. say, something similar like data['users'], this doesn;t work, but there shud be a way to access users array.

Comment: In rails or JS? In JS, data.users would access the array. In rails, it would be params[:users].

Comment: little more help. actually, i am using a sortable element, and serializing it as $(this).sortable('serialize'); it gives me data for users. i have my data for count. now, i need to put them together into  a single entity as data = {count: count, users : <<users array from serialized data>> }. i am not being able to access the users array from serialized data. any idea on how i can do that?

Comment: yepp, actually, there are two sets of data that i get from serializing, thats why i need to serialize. but then, i get this extra data for count by running a different function.